# Required to work unpaid overtime to "make up" for a shorter commute after moving closer to the office

Tags: software-industry, united-states, overtime, commute

So a friend of mine this weekend lamented one of the changes in his employment that happened recently. It got me thinking whether or not you can consider that acceptable.

He works and lives in the US (Michigan to be specific)

Up until around 2 months ago, he used to have a quite lengthy commute. About 1 hour in the morning and 1 hour in the evening. Then, 2 months ago, he moved closer to company premises. Now his commute is about 10 minutes.

His employer (a mid size company) as a result is now forcing him to work 2 hours of unpaid overtime every day, to "keep the active time fair" between him and his colleagues, who supposedly all also have a longer commute. Neither he nor his coworkers got a rebate in hours worked in consideration of their commute.

My initial reaction was that he should start looking for a new job immediately, but according to his experiences practices like this were usual at his 3 previous jobs (didn't affect him at the time but his colleagues).

Now, I'm from Germany, so I obviously have a completely different cultural perspective on this. Is this normal for the software development industry in the USA? (Also feel free to take Michigan into account) If not, what should my friend do besides finding a new job?

**Update:** From what I've heard from him as of couple of weeks ago, he complained to his manager about the policy - which was kept as is despite his complaints, and he was let go for insubordination a week  later. He's now got a new job somewhere else in the area he moved to.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40195/discussion-on-question-by-magisch-required-to-work-unpaid-overtime-to-make-up).

Comment: If he's paid hourly, requiring employeees to work unpaid overtime is illegal.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am glad that his story had a happy ending

Answer (score 329, accepted):

Your friend is being had, if I was him I'd just refuse, do my normal hours and go home. The company can then decide what they want to do about it. In any case I'd be looking for a new job, so if they contemplate disciplinary action over it, they better hurry.

Usually in nominally grey areas (and this just barely qualifies) standing your ground and calling their bluff works well.

Quite important is how you frame your initial refusal, my strategy is to treat it as a joke which gives them an easy way out and we can all have a laugh and be friendly. Getting upset and being too serious and mentioning lawyers etc,. can put someone's back up and although it might come to that in the future, initially it's better to just try and defuse it. So at first I'd just laugh and make a joke out of it.

"Nice one boss, but if you're going to shaft me can you at least use some lubricant." Judgement call on how you word it of course.

If the boss insists they're serious then it's best to be upfront so he knows where you stand which in my case would be there's no way I'm working an extra ten hours a week for the same pay. So something like (judgement call on wording).

"Na... that's just not going to happen boss." and I'd start job hunting the same day while he works out how to handle it. I've never found beating around the bush and expecting people to read your mind to work well in these situations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40304/discussion-on-answer-by-kilisi-required-to-work-unpaid-overtime-to-make-up-for).

Comment: "Sure thing boss but I'll start looking for a house 5 hours drive away."

Comment: If the employee moving closer is only going to benefit the employer, then the employer should subsidize the cost of the move I would think...  I'd gladly work an extra two hours/day in return for them covering my rent/mortgage payments.  :D

Comment: @Murphy haha! hilarious!

Comment: that what you call a micro manager

Comment: I work in Michigan, and have never heard of this.

Answer (score 111):

This is an odd one, but the answer may be complicated.

In the upper peninsula of Michigan there are places that enforce strict environmental rules to protect the community and closed habitat. These places have rules like "no cars" or "mass transit only". These locations have gotten creative with how they compensate employees for their travel time. This is unusual because unlike most cities, transportation is not on the employee, and they can't usually "move closer". You go when the ferry, horse team, or electric bus goes, and that may only be 2 times a day.

There are also other parts (Mackinac Island for one) that ban cars outright.

The real trick are that these are usually smaller towns and don't really have a big business culture. But it does mean having to adjust to the area a bit.

For example, I could see. "We offer 20k a year for a 40 hour work week, but we understand you're coming by ferry so we don't expect you here till 10am and you can leave at 4pm to catch the evening ferry" turning into "But you live here now, 9am to 5pm, you don't need to catch the ferry."

In which case I think the request is totally reasonable. They were effectively paying you to sit on the ferry because it was "the cost of doing business" in that area. Now they're not willing to pay for you to "sit on your couch at home" just because you moved closer.

If on the other hand you were to work 40 hours and now they want you to work 50 hours, that's a bit much.

To me this sounds like your friend "shortened" the story quite a bit, and is leaving out some important parts. They may have to "work" more hours because the company is no longer going to pay for the ferry trip the employee no longer needs to take, but that doesn't mean it's "overtime".

What it really comes down to is; was the company compensating its employees for a long, or time consuming commute, and now refusing to compensate this employee because they are not making that commute (totally fair and IANAL — legal) or are they trying to force him to work a 10 hour day because he is closer (not fair, not IANAL legal)?

Some things the employee could try are

- taking a three hour lunch. If they are trying to get people that live closer to cover time that that people further away are not able to do, then maybe he can suggest a really long lunch to even out the time and give the company what it needs. Of course that will depend on if that has value to the employee.
- convert to 4/10 hour days. This is fairly common, and may be worth it. Again, it gives the company the time coverage, but the employee gets what they need too. Time off.
- Come in early/leave early or come in late/leave late. Again, if the company is just trying to get coverage, they may be willing to have the employee start OR stop in different times to keep an 8 hour day, but still get that coverage.

In short, it's not odd that a company would need to make some kind of adjustment for its environment, specially in the UP. These adjustments usually allow for workers to get compensated for the travel they need to do to get there, because it's not trivial. In these companies it's common to have "close" workers and "far" workers. Close workers not eligible for the compensation for the far workers, and close workers expected to work different times than the far workers to accommodate for environmental restrictions. It is however odd to ask a close worker to work for more hours then a far worker. But due note that a far worker may be considered as "working" when sitting on a ferry waiting to get to work. Close workers may also be required to "fill in" more frequently the far workers, because frankly a far worker may not be able to get there. Usually this is accompanied by some kind of flex time though.

In any case, on salary, if you're supposed to get 40 hours, then normal operations should result in 40 hours, though some special circumstances may come up that mean you're working 50 this week. But that should be a rare thing and not a normal thing.

Comment: Take a 3-hour lunch?

Comment: If the company wants you there from 7am to 6pm and your stuck on an island with no way off, what do you recommend? Go home and chill come back. 7am to 11am -> go home, play xbox -> 2pm to 6pm. Again it depends on if that has value to the employee or the company, but it does happen.

Comment: Where in the UP are there cities like that?

Comment: Well now that's the problem. Mackinac Island is like that, and there are some "areas" in the UP that are like that, but I wouldn't call any of them "cities".  Three Rivers and Sault Ste. Marie are big enough I guess. Again it's hard to call anything up there a city. There is Cedarville too. Again as I said in my answer, these places aren't really prone to big business, the point is that sometimes arrangements are made to accommodate travel situations.

Comment: Also an interesting note, Mackinac island has some of the best high speed internet via cell towers.

Comment: Do employers bundle the "travel allowance" into the salary? I would have expected it to be mentioned separately in the offer letter and the salary statements. In which case, OP could just give up the travel allowance.

Comment: @coteyr I live in Michigan and aside from places like Mackinac Island where the biggest industry is making fudge for tourists and no motor vehicles are allowed, I've never heard of this. I call BS.

Comment: "You go when the ferry, horse team, or electric bus goes [...]" would you share a pic of a horse team please?

Comment: http://www.mackinac-island-insider-tips.com/images/xcarriage-tours-topper-10sec.jpg.pagespeed.ic.apPhZvDh7S.jpg

Answer (score 64):

A long time ago I had a relative who worked for a company that said work started at 08:00, and that employees would not be paid for anything done before that. Because he took the train to work, he arrived  30-45 minutes early; if he took a later train it would be cutting it too close.

So he sat in the lobby reading before he would go into the work space a few minutes before 08:00. Management complained  that he looked like he was goofing off, but he pointed out that they weren't paying for his time, so they couldn't direct his activities. Eventually they amended the rules to allow flex hours.

If I was confident in my ability to either avoid getting in trouble or my ability to find new work, I would start goofing off during the "commute time". At first I would wait until everybody else left at the end of their day, but I would start having these goofing off moments while a few were still there; I would make personal phone calls, read a book, etc. If asked I would say that I was now commuting to home. Hopefully the folly of it would become obvious.

No this is not normal. I have seen fixed start and end time due to shift work, I have even seen shifts for programmers. But I have not run into places that dictate longer hours to balance commutes. The state department of labor might be interested in the situation because they would have a company dictating hours that must be spent with their but in a seat, yet claiming salaried because the employee can manage their own work hours.

Comment: This kind of passive-aggressive behaviour isn't the way to go in my opinion. The request is so insane that OP('s friend) should take a much stronger stance against this.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against passive aggressive initiatives.  It will only annoy people.

Comment: goofing off during work is just a bad idea. probeply resulting in an early Termination of contract and then sitting on your bum without a Job, lovely! And shouldnt the last paragraph be the first?

Comment: Yes, let the Department of Labor know ASAP. Complaints against employers can take weeks to be resolved and you want every one of those days to count in your final tally when calculating damages. You also don't want anyone asking, "Well, why didn't you say anything before?"

Comment: This answer is a bit crazy but I had a good laugh with the *this is me, commuting home right now* while goofying around behavior. Surely not recommended though

Comment: While humorous, I'd say the conditions required to pull this off are quite specific. You would have to be very charismatic and be in a place where this would not be considered incredibly offensive. It' not clear whether OP's friend's workplace is like this, but I would assume it's not.

Comment: This is a silly suggestion.  If you don't agree with being held back for unpaid "commute time" (and you shouldn't), say so and then leave at the end of your normal/paid hours.  Or if you're not willing to take a stand on the issue, stay back and do something useful.  But don't mount an implicit protest by sticking around and doing nothing.  I don't see how anybody wins in that case.

Answer (score 52):

Your friend could try to point out the flaw in the argument:

> Given that I am paid for 6 hours' work, if I lived 3 hours away, making a 6 hour round commute, would you pay me for just travelling to and from the office?

This exposes the silliness of the employer's argument. I'm sure the employer will back down.

Comment: Logically correct, but it’s been my experience that unreasonable employers like this are not interested in rational debate.  The most likely response would be, “Never mind the lip, just do it if you want to keep getting a paycheck.”

Comment: -1 for your last sentence, which is clearly false.

Comment: ...and sorry but this is just stupid. What happens here is *you* agree to this type of logic. By the way, the boss may as well just say "sure, that's fair" and the both of you are done with it. You've already lost as soon as you open your mouth to engage this.

Comment: @djechlin: You are welcome to disagree, but your comments just say that my answer is bad advice. Could you write either an answer of your own, or elaborate in the comments how you think my answer can be improved?

Comment: Your answer could be improved by deleting it :) in the meantime I'm happy to downvote and leave comments explaining why this will backfire. I've upvoted several other answers and have nothing to contribute on top of those.

Comment: @djechlin: 40 people think its a good answer (39 upvoters + me), so I think I'll keep it :-)

Comment: 27 upvotes on the first comment explaining that while your answer is witty and apparently got 40 upvotes, it doesn't actually work. I hope the OP reads that. I would go farther and say your advice actively backfires because when the exchange is fully over your boss knows you humor his logic as fair. Negotiations don't have takebacks.

Comment: Yeah, I won't bother feeding the troll anymore...

Comment: Boss: Yeah, sure. Let me know when you move 3 hours away. ... What do you do now?

Comment: @MaskedMan "Can I have that in writing?" And then of course find some temporary living space 3 hours away. (To be honest, though, I agree this is *not* a good idea.)

Comment: @Jasper Yeah, it is not a good idea, but for benefit of someone else who doesn't see it, I will elaborate: even if the boss agrees (in writing, and all that), you are still a loser. You will spend 6 or more hours travelling everyday. Sure, you get paid for it, but money is not the *only* reason you work. So you are just working on paper, practically you are doing nothing, which is bad for your career. All this trouble just to prove a logical flaw in the policy, when you could rather spend that time on something more useful, such as updating your resume.

Comment: @MaskedMan Ah yes, I assumed that it'd be worded in a way that would allow me cut out the chaff of traveling when I can't get to spend time in the office. Then, I could spend my time however I want (if my resume is my main concern, I could take another job). Looking at the answer though, I see that it's not worded like that. With the poor wording you should just limit the time you stay at the temporary accommodation to a week or two and take public transport to make the best out of that travel time. (Oh, and it's all still a bad idea, no matter the wording.)

Answer (score 44):

No. Even in the US, this is not normal at all! I'm sure your friend knows this. Would he have moved had he known what he would have been in for? I doubt that. His company is acting in very bad faith.

In the US, top tech companies actually reward you for moving closer to your workplace. That's what they do, they reward you for the behavior and the extra expenses they want you to take.

Facebook, for example, is a great example of that. Palantir is another example. They'll pay for a chunk of your rent if you can get a place within a specific distance of the company. Obviously, this means the rent has skyrocketed in those areas, but those companies do not care about that. And the net result is that many Facebook employees have moved near Facebook, or are renting a room near their work during the weekdays, only to go back to their homes on the weekends.

Is this company paying his rent? Did they pay his moving expenses? At this point, your friend is just getting bullied it would seem. Is your friend in a protected class by any chance? If he is, then he might have a case for discrimination since this is such an unusual demand.

In any case, if they want to fire him because he moved, let them. He can't allow them to set this kind of precedent. An employee must be willing to draw the line somewhere. Because if there is no reasonable line the employer is unwilling to cross, it will never end.

Second, he should look at the ulterior motive of whoever thought of this ridiculous idea. I wouldn't be surprised if that person also lived far away and is doing this because he would hate it if he gets pressured into moving closer as a result.

Furthermore, now that some of those gains of the move made may be offset by this stupid decision, the added recurring expense of living closer to the company may no longer make financial sense to him, and perhaps he should consider moving back.

If they don't want a well rested software developer, or if they want an employee who calls in sick more often, or an employee that can't get in because of a snow storm, that's on them. They are setting a bad precedent for the entire company by doing this to him.

And from now on, your friend needs to keep self-disclosure to a bare minimum, or to nothing at all, because it seems anything that he says about his personal life may now be used against him to increase his hours, or decrease his pay, or generally try to take advantage of him in some small but idiotic way. Here is a book on [assertiveness](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006U1JDWY) that may help him with that part.

Comment: I'm not sure about the idea of moving further away, unless it suits the employee themselves. Otherwise it seems like both the employer and the employee are losing out, but nothing is gained, as I don't think the employer will learn their lesson that way? From a self-interest *or* an genuinely altruistic perspective this section of the answer doesn't seem to make sense to me at the moment.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: "... your friend needs to keep self-disclosure to a bare minimum, or to nothing at all ..." While that seems good advice in the general case here, every employer I've worked for requires you to keep your address info up to date.

Comment: "I wouldn't be surprised if that person also lived far away and is doing this because he would hate it if he gets pressured into moving closer as a result. " -- I don't think this works out. If the company gets more work for no extra money when people move closer, that gives the company *more* incentive to pressure people to move closer. Someone who doesn't want to be pressured to move closer should *not* make it be so incredibly advantageous for the company to have employees live nearby.

Comment: Your first five paragraphs are excellent advice but the rest doesn't have much purpose and seems to ramble on a bit. I agree with Joe that moving back is just not a realistic suggestion.

Comment: Companies that pay you extra to live closer are the exception to the rule. 99.9% of us do not work at those companies.

Comment: `Even in the US, this is not normal at all!` Nor in Michigan specifically, if I may be so bold.

Comment: A reasonable number will pay relocation though.

Comment: uhhhh pretty sure FB and Palantir do this *so you can work more hours at them*, just like in the OP's question!

Comment: To add more intimate knowledge - FB developer is one of the most sought after jobs in the world, and yes they treat you great. Palantir is known for stupidly stressful working conditions, you're pretty much expected to live close so that your commute doesn't interfere with the hours you're expected to work there. Two very misleading examples for very different reasons.

Comment: "Because if there is no reasonable line the employer is willing to cross". Should that be "unwilling"?

Answer (score 30):

How many hours was he working before? I mean, if when he had a long commute the company gave him a break and let him work less than 8 hours, and they're saying that now that he has a short commute, there is no longer a reason to give him this special break, I'd say that's reasonable.

But if he was commuting 2 hours and working 8 before, and the company says that now that his commute his 10 minutes he must work 10 hours, no, that's just ridiculous. I've lived and worked in a number of different places in the U.S., and I'm presently working in Michigan, and I've never heard of such a thing.

If he moved again so that he was now 3 hours away, would they count his 6 hour round trip against his 8 hours and let him work just 2 hours per day, while paying him full salary? I really doubt it.

It occurs to me that if there were two people working on a project, and I lived 10 minutes away and the other guy lived an hour away, and there was some crisis that the company had to call someone in on a weekend, and the boss called me and said, "I called you rather than Bob because you're so much closer", I'd probably accept that. There's reasonable taking advantage and unreasonable taking advantage.

As to what to do about it ... As with any conflict with the boss, I wouldn't start out with threats of law suits or contacting government agencies. You'll likely lose your job, so you'd better make sure that anything you win in the lawsuit is worth losing the paycheck. I doubt I'd sue an employer for anything less than failing to pay me, or for something where it's a matter of principle, like the company punished me in some way for my political positions or religious beliefs or something.

My first response would be to just not do it. If the boss doesn't push the matter, you win.

If the boss does say, "Hey, I told you I expect you to work 10 hours a day", I'd politely say that when I took the job, I was told that the normal workday was 8 hours. I might point out that if I moved 3 hours away, I wouldn't expect the company to subtract the commute time, etc.

If he continued to push, I'd talk to his boss.

Comment: Regarding the special break: the employer says it's "to "keep the active time fair" between him and his colleagues, who supposedly all also have a longer commute". So yes, they are *claiming* that everyone's working day is 10 hours including travel, and that since he now lives nearby he no longer needs so much travel subtracted from his working hours. It's almost certainly false on the facts (I doubt that everyone has the same travel time, but they probably all have the same office hours), never mind being an incredibly unusual principle. But that's what they're saying.

Comment: OP states it's **unpaid** overtime. My general suggestion in any case is: don't work unpaid. Ever. Under any circumstance!

Comment: @SteveJessop Yeah, I didn't think that was what he meant, but I made that comment just in case the post was not clearly worded.

Comment: @Josef - Your suggestion would require the OP's friend to not only leave their job but avoid any salaried, full-time job period. If you only ever want to work as a contractor or take lower paying hourly jobs, that's fine, but it's not reasonable to expect that everyone will be able to do that.

Comment: @josef If you get a salaried, as opposed to hourly,  job, you are not paid by the hour but are paid a fixed amount per year. It's expected that you will put in unpaid overtime when necessary. If you're not willing to do this, you're basically writing off having a salaried job.

Comment: If you have a salaried job, you have to keep books yourself about how much you are making per hour. In a salaried job, I expect in return for unpaid overtime when necessary, to get paid free time when possible. Alternatively, I expect that my salary is high enough to still get a reasonable pay for every hour I actually put in.

If this is not the case, I'd work for free. I don't work for other people without monetary compensation. But if that's your fetish, feel free to do so.

Comment: @josef "have to keep books yourself" Well, if you care. But why would you care? RE expect to get comp time or have a higher pay rate: Well, sure. Figuring you work about 2000 hours per year, if I had a choice between getting paid $20/hour or $30,000/year, of course I'd take the hourly. At $40,000/year I'd probably still take the hourly on the reasoning they'lll ikely be some overtime. At $50,000 per year the salary is looking better. Etc.

Comment: "But why would you care?" -- well, you'd care at the point where you're comparing two different jobs with different salaries and different time commitments because one of them asks for way more unpaid overtime than the other. For me it still wouldn't be the rate per hour that's the most important metric. But there are huge cultural differences here, in the most of the EU, most salaried employment is on the expectation that the salary covers basic contracted hours and overtime costs extra. More US salaried employees are running an all-you-can-eat buffet with the employer as the customer ;-)

Comment: ... so that's why the questioner (from Germany) is baffled by the practice of an employer just deciding how many hours you're going to work, whereas many of the US responses even if they don't agree with the detail in this case, are totally comfortable with the idea that there's no such thing as contractual hours. In the EU there are *plenty* of salaried jobs available in which you work, on average over time, your contracted hours or close to it. You're saying that in the US there simply aren't and so Josef (and the questioner's friend) would be out of luck. It's quite a culture clash.

Comment: @Jay: A salaried employee may have to do overtime _as needed_. The fact that your commute got shorter by two hours doesn't mean overtime _is needed_.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, of course. See my original answer above.

Answer (score 16):

Salary or hourly?

As others have already indicated, this is a violation of Michigan (and federal) law for hourly workers.

If he can't convince management of this, then I'd report to the [Michigan Department of Labor](http://www.michigan.gov/lara/0,4601,7-154-59886_27909-39617--,00.html), which can help him get all the back pay for hours already worked.

Obviously there is some risk to reporting, so pull this trigger with caution. (It would also be a violation of Michigan law to fire a worker in retaliation, but there are clearly other ways to make your continued employment less than ideal.)

Comment: They should immediately call the Department of Labor.  They can anonymously speak with someone about the situation and explore options.

Comment: He's a software developer, so very likely is considered exempt.

Comment: worked -> worker, probably.

Comment: And the OP lives in Germany, and so probably does his friend. If this is true, that would make your answer not applicable to the situation.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra OP lives in Germany, his friend lives and works in Michigan, US.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your friend is an hourly employee, this is illegal under federal laws. If the employer does not change their policy to comply with the law immediately, the employee should track their exact hours worked everyday and document it, when they eventually leave the company (perhaps years later), they can then sue for the lost wages. Be sure to document that they have reported to the employer their actual hours worked and the nature of the work they are doing. I would also encourage this employee to let their colleagues know about this policy.

Comment: Are you a lawyer? Because this sounds alot like legal advice

Comment: This is only true if the employee in question is a "non-exempt" employee.  If you are "exempt" and on salary, then there is no legal protection of hours worked.

Comment: If an employee is allowed to work unpaid overtime (i.e. he's *exempt* from overtime rules) then this is perfectly legal. Stupid, but legal. Please don't give legal advice unless you can back up your claims.

Comment: Wow that's some insane federal laws if true, never heard of anything like that for a salaried worker. Kind of negates a lot of the purpose of having them.

Comment: @Lilienthal.  There is a difference between  being _allowed_ to work unpaid overtime and even being _expected occasionally_ to do so and being _required_ to routinely work unpaid overtime.  The latter is illegal, and one does not need to be a lawyer to take protective measures.

Comment: @MichaelJ. Exempt employees have no federal protections when it comes to overtime pay, period. **That's what exempt means.** An employer may require that an exempt employee work 60 hour work weeks while officially listing 40 as the standard and not pay him a dime extra for those 20 hours. As long as the employee is correctly classified as exempt this is perfectly legal. The FLSA confirms this and if you have some legislation or precedent that proves this is illegal you should provide it. Just because it's stupid and immoral that doesn't make it illegal.

Comment: More info is needed from the OP for this to be certain. E.g., the "friend" would seem to need to be paid at a rate less than approx $32.81/hr for 40 hours before it applied; but it might apply anyway. Regardless, it's good advice to document both required and actual hours-worked if not leaving for another job. A future lawsuit might be valid. But consultation with a qualified lawyer should happen soon in order to find best chance of success a to determine best documentation.

Comment: The whole idea of being an "exempt" or "salaried" employee is that you are not being paid by the hour. Your salary is so-many dollars per year, not per hour. When things are busy and deadlines loom, you will work more than 40 hours per week. When things are slow, you'll work less. In exchange for putting in extra hours when needed, it's usually no big deal to take time off for a doctor's appointment or to run an errand. Etc.

Comment: @user2338816 - Where are you getting those numbers from? The [new overtime rule](https://www.dol.gov/whd/overtime/final2016/index.htm) sets the threshold at $913 per week and doesn't kick in until December. It's currently $455 per week which is only $11.37/hour assuming a 40 hour week.

Comment: whoever downvoted this answer is doing the site a heck of a disservice.  It is by any and every measure against the law for the company to take this stance.  They are quite easily at serious risk for fines, penalties, not to mention payment of back wages and damages.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer would do better to correct the answer. Judging by the comments, the correction is easy, hence the downvoting unwarranted.

Comment: @BSMP Number comes from FLSA [**29 U.S. Code § 213 - Exemptions**](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/29/213), (a)(17)(D), which actually states $27.63/hr. But that's for a 40 hr/wk. Extrapolated to 47.5 hrs, the 40 hr rate would have to be $32.81 to come to $27.63 over 47.5 hrs. If there is a fixed required number of hours, then simply calling a position "salaried" doesn't hold. So it's an hourly position regardless.

Comment: I had obviously assumed that the employee in question is hourly; I've edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: @BSMP That's referring to certain employees in *supervisory* positions - they have a much lower minimum.  Software developers not in supervisory positions have their own exemption.

Comment: You might also want to put a prominent "IANAL" disclaimer in there, since you're still getting downvotes. (I gave you a +1, because your answer seems correct to me and because the hourly-assumption is important.)