# Is unpaid overtime a taxable gift to the employer?

Tags: overtime, taxes

Having read [Required to work unpaid overtime to "make up" for a shorter commute after moving closer to the office](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67563/required-to-work-unpaid-overtime-to-make-up-for-a-shorter-commute-after-moving), I recall hearing that in the US doing unpaid work for a company is actually considered a gift that the employer is required to report on their taxes. Is that actually the case? I've never heard of a company doing that.

Comment: If the employer is getting extra work from the employees that it should pay but it does not is already illegal. Reporting it as a gift would be like a drug dealer reporting sales taxes to the state.

Comment: "I recall hearing that in the US doing unpaid work for a company is actually considered a gift" - where did you hear that? Links, please.

Comment: Who said there was a link? :)

Comment: That is to say, when I said "hearing," I was signifying an auditory event, so there are no links. That's why I'm asking, because it was mere hearsay, and I wanted to find out if there was any truth to it.

Comment: This sounds like a legal question. I believe legal questions are generally considered off-topic.

Comment: @DonBranson only if you litherly donate your time, which is possible since your work hours have a certain currency value.

Comment: @SJuan76 The drug dealer is, however, required to claim the sales as income for the purpose of federal income taxes or he can be charged with tax evasion as well as drug dealing.

Comment: @Perkins I thought the supreme court ruled that you cannot be convicted in situations like that because of the constitutional fifth amendment; the dealer is not forced to tell the government anything that could count as being a witness against him/herself.

Comment: @Aaron From what I understand, they're not allowed to use the records to investigate or prosecute him for drug dealing.  They'd rather have to work a little harder to catch him at dealing drugs than miss out on the tax revenue.

Answer (score 6):

> Is unpaid overtime a taxable gift to the employer?

**No, this is simply not true.** When an employee works overtime one of two things happen:

- the employee is either exempt from FLSA overtime rules and receives nothing for it,
- or the employee is owed overtime pay for all time worked *over the applicable FLSA overtime threshold in the applicable FLSA work period* (typically 40 hours per week)

An employee who is owed overtime is legally unable to give up his right to overtime pay. **He must be paid for it** as part of the regular pay cycle (i.e. within X weeks as defined by state/federal law). Employees who were not paid overtime and can prove that they worked overtime while non-exempt are eligible for backpay *years* down the line and the employer would be subject to heavy fines. This may be the source for the rumour you've heard.

For more details, check [my answer here where I go into obsessive amounts of detail on exempt and non-exempt status](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/52303/25739).

---

<sup>*I am not a legal professional and this answer does not constitute legal advice. It is only intended to be a summary of the applicable laws as they apply in general.*</sup>

Comment: "Legally unable to give his right": There was a thread a while ago about an employer having problems to force an employee _not_ to do unpaid overtime. Which seemed a ridiculous problem until it was pointed out that the employee refusing to leave could sue for payment years later.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes it's brought up occasionally as one of the quirks that come with the employee protection laws and can prevent employees who want to go above and beyond from volunteering at crunch time. But the argument can be made that those who want to do it routinely should be rewarded with overtime pay or reclassified as exempt (if legally possible). You may also be thinking of a related answer [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30540/mandatory-one-hour-lunch-is-it-common-practice-in-uk-it/30558#30558) about mandatory lunch breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard this approach, but working for wages is usually governed by each state's department of labor and unless you are an [Exempt Employee](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiV5Zqe4vDMAhVM4yYKHc6QAb8QFggfMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftopics.hrhero.com%2Fexempt-vs-non-exempt-employees%2F&usg=AFQjCNFZxTHr-9WeVmdOzdShZRvpIOndog&sig2=4o13bCV_bfZ320JaDe5hEw%20Exempt%20Employye), you can not be forced or asked to be working overtime without pay. It is illegal. If you are non-exempt, you get paid for each hour or smallest fraction allowed in your employment contract, for time worked.

When you are exempt, you are considered to be above average compensated and you are not subject to overtime pay. I am not sure what your situation is. In exempt employee contracts, there usually is a clause saying that some out of normal working hours and some weekend work is expected of you, which goes without saying, the compensation is already in your pay, so you shouldn't expect overtime or any other method of compensation.